# Отправка файла на сайт через Python

Tags: python, html

Мне нужно на определённый сайт каким-то образом отправить файл, автоматически через питон. Файл вручную можно отправить либо drag&drop либо нажать на кнопку и выбрать файл через открывшееся окно.
Также нужно вписать в input окно определённый текст, затем нажать кнопку отправки. Возможно ли это сделать при помощи python без открытия браузера и каких-либо действий от пользователя? Просто открыть файл .py и всё само сделается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да. Например с помощью селениума. Для начала прописать что бы браузер не открывался в видимом окне headless. Что бы эмулировать нажатие нужно использовать локатор и метод .click() что бы эмулировать ввод то метод .send_keys

Comment: Спасибо! Да, selenium идеально подойдёт для решения моих целей.